# Slide Up Slide Down at one time jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I try to make *`slide up`* and *`slide down`* divs at one time.

I want the first *`div slide down`* an the hidden next *`div slide up`*

I would like to make these elements overlap when animated

**jQuery**

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.plus').click(function () {
                   $('header h1').animate({ 'margin-top': '999px', opacity: 'toggle' }, 1500);
                   $('header h2').animate({ 'margin-top': '0px', opacity: 'show' }, 1200);
            });

            $('.minus').click(function () {
                  $('header h2').hide('slow');
                  $('header h1').show('slow');
             });
           });
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/n7Ejs/

Comment: Check this link. http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Comment: m not sure what you want?? do you want an accordion?? if yes then see this: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#fillspace

Comment: no...only animate down the first div and the second animate up when u click a button plus/minus something like show hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.delay(timeToWait)`, you should be able to fine tune the animation sequence/order to your needs. I've modified your code on jsFiddle. I'm not sure if it's what you're attempting to achieve, but hope it helps! http://jsfiddle.net/EVN3v/

Comment: Yes something like this...only the small problem that i want let in relative position the h1 h2

Comment: If you wish to keep `position : relative;`, you were right to use `margin-top`. Here's the modified version - http://jsfiddle.net/6yNGm/

Comment: Glad to help. Just keep in mind that the elements aren't actually overlapping. Use the `.delay()` to keep them from clashing and popping up at the same time. Cheers!